# MySQL has indexed tables and EXPLAIN looks good, but still not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I am trying to optimize a query, and all looks well when I got to "EXPLAIN" it, but it's still coming up in the "log_queries_not_using_index".

Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.id_id,t1.change_id,t1.like_id,t1.dislike_id,t1.user_id,t1.from_id,t1.date_id,t1.type_id,t1.photo_id,t1.mobile_id,t1.mobiletype_id,t1.linked_id 
FROM recent AS t1 
LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id_id 
WHERE t2.active_id=1 AND t1.postedacommenton_id='0'  AND t1.type_id!='Friends' 
ORDER BY t1.id_id DESC LIMIT 35;
```

So it grabs like a 'wallpost' data, and then I joined in the USERS table to make sure the user is still an active user (the number 1), and two small other "ANDs".

When I run this with the EXPLAIN in phpmyadmin it shows

```
id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                       | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | t1    | index  | user_id           | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                      | 35   | Using where
1  | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active_id | PRIMARY | 4       | hnet_user_info.t1.user_id | 1    | Using where
```

It shows the t1 query found 35 rows using "WHERE", and the t2 query found 1 row (the user), using "WHERE"

So I can't figure out why it's showing up in the log_queries_not_using_index report.

Any tips? I can post more info if you need it.

Comment: For 35x1 row cardinality, why does an index matter? Is the query actually slow? (The query planner is likely thinking the same thing: it will only choose an index when it estimates it will "be beneficial" to do so.)

Comment: I'm just trying to weed out all my queries that aren't using indexes, and this one seems to be popping up. It's not slow though - when you are on the site it takes about 1 second to load, if that. I set my "Slow Query" time to 20 seconds to be sure that this error wasn't appearing because of a long loading time.

Comment: A query that takes 1 second is a slow query in my book - log the *actual* time the query (and *only* the query) takes to execute. Then decide if this query is an issue or not. Use the 97/3 rule.

Comment: Here's the query time data: Showing rows 35 - 34 ( 35 total, Query took 0.0013 sec) [id_id: 363522 - 363482]

Comment: Yeah, 1.3 milliseconds .. that's *not* a problem. Trust the database engine (it obviously knows what it is doing in this case), ignore the "log warning", and use the 97/3 rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr; ignore the "not using index warning".** A query execution time of 1.3 milliseconds is *not a problem*; there is nothing to optimize here - look at the *entire* performance profile to find bottlenecks.

Trust the database engine. The database query planner will use indices *when* it determines that doing so is beneficial. In this case, due to the low [cardinality estimates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimizer#Cost_estimation) (35x1), the query planner decided that there was no reason to use indices for the actual execution plan. If indices were used in a trivial case like this it could actually increase the query execution time.

As always, use the 97/3 rule.

Comment: Perfect, and thank you for the explanation. I used to have a high "Handler read rnd" value and a high "Handler read rnd next". Sometimes "Handler read rnd next" was over 4 gigs after 2 days. Currently the server has been running for 20 hours and the "Handler read rnd" value is 277.1 k, and the "Handler read rnd next" value is at 4.9 M. My site is like a facebook style site, and has about 20 active members on at any given time. Are these values small and at a good size? This is the only site I've ever really programmed this intensely so I have to nothing to compare those numbers to